# How can i get response coming from web server

Tags: json, jsp

i have a form, i am asking customer to enter few details,

```
<form id="redirectForm" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" action="https://test.test.com//api/v1/order/create" > 
    customerName:   <input type="text" name="customerName" value=<%=customerName %> />
    customerEmail:  <input type="text" name="customerEmail" value=<%=customerEmail %> /><br><br>
customerPhone: <input type="text" name="customerPhone" value=<%=customerPhone %> /><br><br>
signature:<input type="text" name="signature" value=<%=signature %>     />
```

On submit page redirect according to action of form and display a JSON type response(status + payment link). 
response is like:

```
{"status":"OK","paymentLink":"https:\/\/test.test.com\/billpay\/order\/3ackwtoyn7oks4416fomn"}
```

Help me out with this
i am working in jsp.
thank you in advance.

Comment: is response in JSON

Comment: beacause it's syntax looks like a JSON

Comment: i dont know what is this, i need to access this. yes it looks like JSON. I am very beginner also.

Comment: in browser you are getting response link?

Comment: that is same as i passed in action url of form

Comment: while submitting the form you have to redirect to https:\/\/test.test.com\/billpay\/order\/3ackwtoyn7oks4416fomn   to this Url. i am correct?

Comment: yes you are correct and on this page we are getting some response which is status and payment_link.

Comment: if you save this response in JSON then it will be very easy to get url...

Comment: just a little tutorial for JSON will be enough to get that url easily.

Comment: yes it will be easy  but how to save this response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this look like a simple Webservice answer (not a full HTML page), I would use Ajax to send the form and manage the response.

With JQuery, this is easy using [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: //the URL
    data: //the form value
    method: //GET/POST
    success: function(response){
        //decode the JSON response...
        var url = $.parseJSON(response).paymentLink;
        //then redirect / not sure since this could be cross-domain...
        window.loacation = url;
    },
    error: function(error){
        ...
    }
})
```

The only think is that the form should not be send with a submit input, you need to link a button to a function doing this Ajax call.

This can be done without JQuery but I can write this from memory ;)

---

If you can edit the JSP creating the response, you could generate an HTML to return the value directly.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        window.location.href = '${paymentLink}';
    </script>
</head>
<body>
     Redirection ... 
     <br>If nothing happend, you can <a href='${paymentLink}'>click here</a> to be redirected.
</body>
</html>
```

Where `${paymentLink}` is a EL that will print the value of this variable (well the name it has on the server) to complete the script with the URL.

Once it is received by the client, it will be executed.

Of course, this will not be cross-domain on every browser. If this is not, you will need to provide the link to the user with `<a href='${paymentLink}'>Redirection</a>` itsefl.

Comment: can we do this in another way bcz i dont know ajax.

Comment: @PriyankaGoyal Since the server only return a JSON, you need to manage it somewhere, **if you can update the JSP creating the response, yes you can**. But all you need to know about ajax is that this is an asynchronous requester, instead of simple reloading a page, it send the request in the background and let you manage the response. Here, since all you receive is a text (in form of JSON), you are force to manage it like this (I don't know other solution to manage JSON response).

Comment: @PriyankaGoyal, I have added a solution if you can update the  JSP that generate the response. Give me a feedback on this ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

while submitting the form write one JS function and get the URL value.

```
     <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
           function check(){

//here you have to get value using element name or id (val1,val2,val3)
                $.ajax({ 
                    type:'GET',
                    data: {customerName: val1, customerEmail: val2,customerPhone: val3},
                    url:'https://test.test.com/billpay/order/3ackwtoyn7oks4416fomn',// Replace with Your Exact URL
                    success: function(response){
                        alert(response);
                         var json = JSON.parse(response);
                         var values = json.values;

                         for(var i in values)
                         {
                            var New_redirect = values[i].address;
                            alert(values[i].address);

                         }

                         window.loacation=New_redirect;
                    }
                });
            })

}
            </script>


            </head>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135451/discussion-on-answer-by-karthick-anbazhagan-how-can-i-get-response-coming-from-w).

Answer (score 0):

i think you  are looking for response message and redirecting to somewhere
if so you can use the following code

```
    if(condition)
{
response.sendRedirect("urpage.jsp");
}
```

or

```
  if(condition)
    {
    request.getRequestDispacher("page.jsp");//enter the name of page you want to redirect inside ""
}
```

Comment: Didn't write Servlet from a long time, is it cross-domain ?

Comment: this is different thing